# Fetch data 24 hours ago, add in timestamp

Tags: r

I have a data frame in r that contains readings each five minutes of an hour. I want to add in same row data from exact 24 hours before for each row.

How can I do that ?

I am trying to search from net and found solution like `as.Date("2020-01-11")-1` but not able to make them work for my data. Please help in that.

Here is an example of my data frame. It contains data of about 3 months, almost 10,000 rows. I put only 3 rows for example:

```
>df
         timestamp           Var1         Var2        Var3 
1    2018-07-20 13:50:00   32.0358        28.1        3.6       
2    2018-07-20 13:55:00   32.0358        28.0        2.5       
3    2018-07-20 14:00:00   32.0358        28.1        2.2
```

the values of 24 hours ago data come into e.g. `Var4 Var5 Var6`

**EDIT**
     Like the 1st row has values of 3 vars on timestamp  2018-07-20 13:50:00. I want to add what was value of these 3 vars exactly 24 hours ago i.e. on  2018-07-19 13:50:00, i.e. one day ago at same time to 3 new vars e.g. var4, var5, var6. I want to basically observe variation of these over 24 hours.
I hope its helps in understanding my question.

Comment: Please share a reproducible example along with expected output. Thanks

Comment: I read your question 3 times and still have no clue of what you want to do.

Comment: @FelixPhl: I tried to make clear. I will edit now to add more detail by example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am still not sure if I understood what you want but here is a very simple solution where you could start from:

```
library(dplyr)
df <- data.frame(timestamp = c("2018-07-20 13:00", "2018-07-20 14:00", "2018-07-21 13:00", "2018-07-21 14:00"),
             var1 = c(1,2,3,4))
df$timestamp <- as.POSIXct(df$timestamp)

#copy the first dataframe and modify the timestamp
df2 <- data.frame(timestamp = df$timestamp + 60*60*24,
              var2 = df$var1)

#then merge the second df with the first one
df <- left_join(df,df2, by = "timestamp")

df
            timestamp var1 var2
1 2018-07-20 13:00:00    1   NA
2 2018-07-20 14:00:00    2   NA
3 2018-07-21 13:00:00    3    1
4 2018-07-21 14:00:00    4    2
```

Comment: Thank you. I forget to add now added in OP that these are 3 example rows. I have data of about 3 months almost 10,000 rows.

Comment: @XCeptable what's the problem? if you copy your first data.frame it will copy all the data no matter how many rows you have.

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to create a new column subtracting 24hours from `timestamp` and join this data with itself to get new columns next to each other.

```
df$timestamp <- as.POSIXct(df$timestamp, tz = "UTC")
df$timestamp1 <- df$timestamp - 86400
merge(df, df, by.x = "timestamp", by.y = "timestamp1", all.x = TRUE)
```